# ReactNative Unable to build for android. react-native-maps:debugRuntimeClasspath

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm noob using ReactNative, I've cloned a react-native project from bitbucket, I'm getting this error related with react-native-maps.

it having Android emulator running, also sdk configured in local.properties file.

```
react-native run-android
```

output this

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
>   Parsing json file: C:\Project\android\app\google-services.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

  > Failed to transform file 'c1ff7541912b40d9b50e133b545d5364' to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name} using transform LibrarySymbolTableTransform
  >   java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no estß permitido en el pr¾logo.
  >   Failed to transform file 'c1ff7541912b40d9b50e133b545d5364' to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name} using transform LibrarySymbolTableTransform
  >   java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; El contenido no estß permitido en el pr¾logo.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
61 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 54 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

versions I use.

```
yarn -v
1.5.1

npm -v
5.6.0

node -v
v9.8.0

react-native -version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.51.0
```

gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-sentry')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar"
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':RCTTwilioChat')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
}
```

I've tryed `react-native link`, but it stucks.

If someone could to guide me about how fix this, it would be great.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem.
the problem was some kind of conflict between firebase and react-native-maps's google maps library included. I had to test multiple times removing, changing each version of google play services, but it was not working.

this was my solution:

from android studio I've changed in gradle project file this:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

to

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

I've removed also the jcenter() methods inside repositories{} beccause those are not included in this version.

after that

```
build > sync
build > clean
build > rebuild
```

then from powershell

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your internet connection is working. Sometimes react native apps can't build without internet facility.

If it works run the following command to clean gradle cash.

```
gradlew clean
```

Then try it again.